# Android Intent using Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap

I'm using intents to call an application with text parameter

```
 String text = "Text here"; 
       Intent intent = new Intent("my.package");  
       intent.setType("text/plain"); 
       intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text); 
       startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way to do the same using Apache Cordova? I'm using this code , my app is called but the text is not received:

```
  window.plugins.launcher. launch(
    {packageName:'my.package',
    dataType:'text/plain',
        extras: [
            {"name":"android.intent.extra.TEXT", "value":"text", "dataType":"CharArray"}
        ]}, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Plugin: https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-app-launcher

Comment: try this  https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent

Comment: I'm using the plugin that I put in my question